Как ставить многоточие?
Какой из вариантов правильный, если допустить, что каждая выдержка из статьи идет в сокращенном виде не с начала предложения, а с середины.
1. Группа В. Буданова совершила первовосхождение на Птыш. …Военные топографы… группы Церетелли совершили первое советское восхождение на Нахар.
2. <...> …Военные топографы … группы Церетелли совершили первое советское восхождение на Нахар.
3. <...> …Военные топографы …группы Церетелли совершили первое советское восхождение на Нахар.

✦ Я думаю, что правильно надо написать так (первый вариант):
«Группа В. Буданова совершила первовосхождение на Птыш. ...Военные топографы... группы Церетелли совершили первое советское восхождение на Нахар».
Из справочника А. Э. Мильчина и Л. К. Чельцовой:

8.4.1. Цитаты, начинающиеся с прописной буквы
Это цитаты:
<...>
2. Начинающие собой фразу и идущие после точки, завершающей предшествующее предложение осн. текста, даже если первые слова цитируемого предложения опущены. Напр.:
В источнике:
А поэзия, прости господи, должна быть глуповата.
В цитате:
Здесь уместно напомнить пушкинские слова. «...Поэзия... должна быть глуповата», — писал поэт.

• [8.2.1] Цитата на письме заключается в кавычки.
• [8.5.5] Многоточие от следующего за ним слова пробелом не отделяется (...Военные).
Многоточие, идущее после слова, также от него пробелом не отделяется (топографы...)
• Словосочетание военные топографы получается обрамленным многоточиями.
• [8.5.4] При отсутствии нескольких предложений можно было бы использовать угловые скобки в том месте, где пропущена бо́льшая часть текста. Например:
«Группа В. Буданова совершила первовосхождение на Птыш. <...> Военные топографы... группы Церетелли совершили первое советское восхождение на Нахар».
• Вы уверены, что фамилия Церетелли написана правильно?
Очень подробно здесь: Цитаты.
